# How to fix "The following _Exception was thrown during performLayout(): Exception: minIntrinsicWidth is greater than maxIntrinsicWidth (0)."

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to parse a JSON file from my assets folder. Here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "Simple Text"
            },
            {
                "mode": "latex",
                "value": "\frac00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "text exapple4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And here is what I have done so far:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var txt;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future:
            DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/paragraph.json"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          var mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          if (mydata != null) {
            return SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  List<dynamic> arr = mydata[0]["1"];
                  arr.forEach((element) {
                    print(element);
                    txt = CaTeX(mydata[0]["1"][1]["value"]);
                  });
                  return txt;
                }));
          } else {
            return SizeTransition(
                axis: Axis.vertical,
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          }
        });
  }
```

When I run my code it gives me this error:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
> ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following _Exception was thrown during performLayout(): Exception:
> minIntrinsicWidth (5.328125) is greater than maxIntrinsicWidth (0).
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> NodeWidget-[#5aef7]
> file:///Users/amin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/catex-0.0.1+6/li
> b/src/parsing/character.dart:21:12
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 214:49 throw* lib/_engine/engine/text/measurement.dart 532:5
> _applySubPixelRoundingHack lib/_engine/engine/text/measurement.dart 418:9 [_measureSingleLineParagraph]
> lib/_engine/engine/text/measurement.dart 348:16 [_doMeasure]
> lib/_engine/engine/text/measurement.dart 258:14 measure
> lib/_engine/engine/text/paragraph.dart 277:46 layout
> packages/flutter/src/painting/text_painter.dart 569:16 layout
> packages/catex/src/rendering/character.dart 41:14 configure
> packages/catex/src/rendering/rendering.dart 147:5 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/catex/src/rendering/rendering.dart 61:10 sizeChildNode
> packages/catex/src/rendering/group.dart 41:30 configure
> packages/catex/src/rendering/rendering.dart 147:5 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/catex/src/rendering/rendering.dart 324:11 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 396:13 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 115:13 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 1269:11 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 115:13 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 115:13 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart 201:26 performLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7 layout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart 137:11
> performLayout packages/flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart
> 377:11 performLayout packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1769:7
> layout packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart 471:12
> layoutChildSequence packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart
> 1465:12 [_attemptLayout] packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart
> 1374:20 performLayout packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart
> 1632:7 [_layoutWithoutResize]
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 889:17 flushLayout
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 404:19 drawFrame
> packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 867:13 drawFrame
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 286:5
> [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
> packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1117:15
> [_invokeFrameCallback] packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart
> 1056:9 handleDrawFrame packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart
> 972:5 [_handleDrawFrame] lib/_engine/engine/window.dart 743:13
> _invoke lib/_engine/engine/window.dart 356:5 invokeOnDrawFrame lib/_engine/engine.dart 219:18
>
> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was
> fired: RenderCharacter#b5f9a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:   creator:
> NodeWidget-[#5aef7] ←
> NodeWidget-[#da2b7] ← _TreeWidget ←
> CaTeX ← Builder ← Align ← ClipRect ← SizeTransition ← FutureBuilder
> ← CardItem ←
> RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← ⋯   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=620.0,
> 0.0<=h<=Infinity)   size: MISSING This RenderObject has no descendants.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> ════════════════════ Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
> invalid member on null: 'height' Another exception was thrown:
> NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'width' Another exception
> was thrown: Assertion failed:
> file:///Users/amin/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1702:12
> Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
> file:///Users/amin/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1702:12

complete code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9drwehcozrewhht/tutorial_page.dart?dl=0

Comment: there is an earlier error in the log, see the log for the first error, fix it or post it here

Comment: @neuromancer, thanks for noticing, I updated my post

Comment: Post the code of NodeWidget

Comment: I uploaded the whole file